# How to split a row by specific string length in a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a file like this:

```
system
1000
    1VEA      C    1   9.294  11.244  11.083
    1VEA     C1    2   9.324  11.375  11.161
    1VEA      H    3   9.243  11.396  11.232
...
 1203VEA    H2092601  20.738  16.293   7.837
 1203VEA    H2192602  20.900  16.225   7.869
 1203VEA    H2292603  20.822  16.330   7.989
```

I want to generate a dataframe which include 6 columns. I used following command to

```py
    df = pd.read_csv('system.gro', skiprows=[0,1], delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
```

generate this dataframe. However, when it came to the row started with 1203, columns between H20 and 92601 has no white space and I cannot just use above command to split it. I used to split the line string by specific length like:

```py
    f1 = open(fileName, 'r')
    for line in f1.readlines():
         atomName = line[8:15].strip(' ')
         globalIdx = int(line[15:20].strip(' '))
```

But it takes really long time to deal with the file. Does anyone has any idea about how to deal with this using dataframe?

Comment: This looks more like a data quality issue or something with the settings while exporting the file. Cant you ask for a file with an actualy delimiter, for example the `|` ?

Comment: instead of `pd.read_csv` use `pd.read_fwf`. I am not sure how the `.strip()` would work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [SRT HellKitty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9221467/srt-hellkitty) in the comments, use `pd.read_fwf` (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)) like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data="""
   1VEA      C    1   9.294  11.244  11.083
   1VEA     C1    2   9.324  11.375  11.161
   1VEA      H    3   9.243  11.396  11.232
1203VEA    H2092601  20.738  16.293   7.837
1203VEA    H2192602  20.900  16.225   7.869
1203VEA    H2292603  20.822  16.330   7.989
"""

### make sure that the widths are correct!
df=pd.read_fwf(pd.compat.StringIO(data),colspecs=[(0,8),(8,14),(14,20),(20,28),(28,36),(36,44)])
print(df)
```

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, I wasn't aware of that, as I usually seldom read from string :) and I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Really appreciate about the answers!